# Sharing the config file for vim and gvim

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I have gvim installed as well as vim. I want gvim and vim to share the same config file. How can I do that?

Comment: They should, already. Where are your config files located?

Comment: they already do, .gvimrc usually contains additional settings that are gvim specific. .vimrc still remains the main config file

Answer (score 6):

Vim reads `~/.vimrc`; gvim reads `~/.gvimrc` as well as `~/.vimrc`.

So simply put your commands into `~/.vimrc` (and put the GUI-specific commands into `~/.gvimrc`).

Newer Vims also look at `~/.vim/vimrc` and `~/.vim/gvimrc`.

Comment: its `~/.vim/vimrc` and `~/.vim/gvimrc`

Comment: yes, true. details can be found by typing **:he vimrc** in vim

Answer (score 5):

You can also use something along the following lines in your `vimrc`:

```
if has('gui')
    set foo=bar
    ...
endif
```

Answer (score 5):

`has('gui')` return True if Vim has a GUI compiled in (regardless of whether you're running the terminal vim or not). A better option is `has('gui_running')`, which only returns True if the GUI is actually running.